# What's the most efficient way to match values between 2 tables based on most recent prior date?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I've got two tables in MS SQL Server:

`dailyt` - which contains daily data:

```
date             val
---------------------
2014-05-22       10
2014-05-21       9.5
2014-05-20       9
2014-05-19       8
2014-05-18       7.5
etc...
```

And `periodt` - which contains data coming in at irregular periods:

```
date             val
---------------------
2014-05-21       2
2014-05-18       1
```

Given a row in `dailyt`, I want to adjust its value by adding the corresponding value in `periodt` with the closest date prior or equal to the date of the `dailyt` row.  So, the output would look like:

`addt`

```
date             val
---------------------
2014-05-22       12      <- add 2 from 2014-05-21
2014-05-21       11.5    <- add 2 from 2014-05-21
2014-05-20       10      <- add 1 from 2014-05-18
2014-05-19       9       <- add 1 from 2014-05-18
2014-05-18       8.5     <- add 1 from 2014-05-18
```

I know that one way to do this is to join the `dailyt` and `periodt` tables on `periodt.date <= dailyt.date` and then imposing a `ROW_NUMBER() (PARTITION BY dailyt.date ORDER BY periodt.date DESC)` condition, and then having a `WHERE` condition on the row number to = 1.

Is there another way to do this that would be more efficient?  Or is this pretty much optimal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think using [APPLY](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175156%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) would be the most efficient way:

```
SELECT  d.Val,
        p.Val,
        NewVal = d.Val + ISNULL(p.Val, 0)
FROM    Dailyt AS d
        OUTER APPLY
        (   SELECT  TOP 1 Val
            FROM    Periodt p
            WHERE   p.Date <= d.Date
            ORDER BY p.Date DESC
        ) AS p;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4f1d6/1)**

Answer (score 0):

If there relatively very few `periodt` rows, then there is an option that may prove quite efficient.

Convert `periodt` into a From/To ranges table using subqueries or CTEs. (*Obviously performance depends on how efficiently this initial step can be done, which is why a small number of `periodt` rows is preferable.*) Then the join to `dailyt` will be extremely efficient. E.g.

```
;WITH PIds AS (
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY PDate) RN, *
        FROM   @periodt
    ),
    PRange AS (
        SELECT  f.PDate AS FromDate, t.PDate as ToDate, f.PVal
        FROM    PIds f
                LEFT OUTER JOIN PIds t ON
                  t.RN = f.RN + 1
    )
SELECT  d.*, p.PVal
FROM    @dailyt d
        LEFT OUTER JOIN PRange p ON
            d.DDate >= p.FromDate
        AND (d.DDate < p.ToDate OR p.ToDate IS NULL)
ORDER BY 1 DESC
```

---

If you want to try the query, the following produces the sample data using table variables. Note I added an extra row to `dailyt` to demonstrate no `periodt` entries with a smaller date.

```
DECLARE  @dailyt table (
    DDate date NOT NULL,
    DVal float NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @dailyt(DDate, DVal)
          SELECT '20140522', 10
UNION ALL SELECT '20140521', 9.5
UNION ALL SELECT '20140520', 9
UNION ALL SELECT '20140519', 8
UNION ALL SELECT '20140518', 7.5
UNION ALL SELECT '20140517', 6.5

DECLARE @periodt table (
    PDate date NOT NULL,
    PVal int NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO @periodt
          SELECT '20140521', 2
UNION ALL SELECT '20140518', 1
```