# SQL to get max(amount) from 2 different table and join them

Tags: sql

What I am trying to achieve:
We are doing this so that the user can get the check details in the distribution lines in the obiee reports.
I want to populate the check Ids for the Distribution lines, by taking the check number which has max(check_amount) from the payment lines.

I have INVC table which gives INV ID, CHECK ID, TRANSCTN TYP, VOID FLG, INV LIN AMT and CHECK DTLS table which gives Check num, Check amount. both are joined using check id=check_num.

Also, there are two scenarios here which we have to consider. One with the reversal flag(we should exclude those) and the other even though the check num's are diff, we should populate the distribution line with max check amount details from the payment line

```
INV_ID| CHECK_ID    CHK_AMT TRANSCTN_TYP    VOID FLG    INV_LIN_AMT
100   |                 DISTRIBUTION                1450
100   | 1234            1200    PAYMNT      
100   | 2345            250 PAYMNT  




INV_ID  CHECK_ID    CHK_AMT TRANSCTN_TYP    VOID_FLG    INV_LIN_AMT
200                 DISTRIBUTION                100
200 1459            100 PAYMNT            Y 
200 1459            -100    PAYMNT            Y 
200 2356             100    PAYMNT
```

I have to join two different tables and create a view and write a update statement on top it and automate it.

Can anybody share your email, so I can send you all details along with sample data.

Sample Query:

select distinct T105231.INVOICE_ID as c1,
     T105231.TRANSACTION_SOURCE as c2,
     T105231.INVOICE_NUM as c3,
     cast(cast(T105231.INVOICE_ID as  NUMERIC(9, 0) ) as  CHARACTER ( 50 ) ) as c4,
     T105231.INVOICE_AMT as c5,
     T104962.CHECK_NUM as c6
from

```
      INV_DTL_ALL_F_V T105231 left outer join 
     AP_CHECK_NUMBER T104962 On T104962.CHECK_NUM = T105231.CHECK_ID
```

Comment: Code would help to motivate potential answerers.

Comment: Could you add some script and organize data into more readable form. Thanks

Comment: Given the sample data you've posted, exactly what output would you like to receive from it? (What **exactly** would the desired result be?) I'm afraid I can't make any sense out of the text in your question when I try to match it to the data you've posted.

Comment: I suggest you provide some sample inputs and sample output.

Comment: I also reverted your edit, because your attempt at formatting only made things much worse. You can inspect the question to see how it will appear while entering/editing it by looking right below where you're typing; there is a WYSIWYG-style preview area that lets you see how it will appear when it's posted. It helps if you use it. :-)

Comment: Thanks for your prompt replies.. Can I have your email so I can email you the details along with some sample data?? I am not sure how to format here.

Comment: Can I not add any attachments?

Comment: @user3665997 No, we're not a free email support service. We're also not interested in wading through large attachments. If you provide a small number of sample input and output rows that show what you're struggling with, someone may be able to help. More importantly others may benefit from the same question.

Comment: @user3665997 Here's an example of how to show [sample data](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23812563/224704) for your question.